# copy folder, subfolders and files from a path to another path in python via a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, directory, shutil

I want to copy some folders and files from a path to another path. for example, I want to copy the folder(called folder1) which has some other subfolders and some files inside itself to another folder(dst). In my program, at the first, I want to check if there is a folder named folder1 in destination folder and if not, create a folder with folder1 name and then copy the content of folder1 to target. In addition, maybe we have folder1 in the target path, but there are some subfolders of folder1 which don't exist in target and we must use a recursive function for that. Here is my recursive function for this purpose:

```
def CopyFol_Subfolders(src, src_folder, dst):
    Dir = next(os.walk(src))[1]
    sub_files = ""
    sub_files = next(os.walk(src))[2]
    if not os.path.exists(dst + "/" + src_folder):
        os.makedirs(dst + "/" + src_folder)
        shutil.copy2(src + "/" + src_folder, dst + "/" + src_folder)

    elif os.path.exists(src + "/" + src_folder) and is_exist_file(src+"/"+src_folder,dst+"/"+src_folder,sub_files):
        copy_files(sub_files, src+"/"+src_folder, dst+"/"+src_folder)
    else:
        subfolders = ""
        subfolders = next(os.walk(src + "/" + src_folder+"/"))[1]
        for folder in subfolders:
            CopyFol_Subfolders(src + "/" + src_folder, folder, dst + "/" + src_folder)
```

the `copy_files` function will copy the files from `src +"/"+src_folder` to `dst+"/"+src_folder`

I be confused and this does not work. I got different errors in `shutil.copy2` which tell me `x is not a file` or `x is a directory`.
Can please some one check logic of my recursive function and let me know what is this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.path.isdir` instead of `os.path.exists` to ensure that it can only be a directory not a file. And `os.path.join` is better than concatenating path strings by ourselves.

```
def CopyFol_Subfolders(src, dst):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            CopyFol_Subfolders(s, d)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

Comment: this kind of answer suites in comment.

Comment: this is a complete answer and  helped me so mcuh. Thank you @frankyjuang

Comment: Hi @frankyjuang, Excuse me, I am using your codes in my program. But it seems overwrite some of files or folders which their names are the same in the target and src path. Can you please help me how can I change the code in a way that those files and folders do not be overwrite? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by overwrite? Can you provide detailed directory/file structures?