# Copy files to same directory with another name

Tags: python, path, directory, shutil

I need to copy all html files inside the same directory with another name and I need to navigate all directories inside the source directory.

Here is my code so far,

```
import os
import shutil
os.chdir('/') 

dir_src = ("/home/winpc/test/copy/")

for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        shutil.copy( dir_src + filename, dir_src)
    print(filename)
```

Comment: So basically *renaming* each file? `os.rename` and `glob` might help

Comment: Actually i do not need to rename.I need to remain original file as it is.I need to get a copy to same folder with another name

Comment: Why not issue a shell command?  The `find` and `copy` functions all have recursive switches that will alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Solution

```
import os
import shutil

def navigate_and_rename(src):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            navigate_and_rename(s)
        else if s.endswith(".html"):
            shutil.copy(s, os.path.join(src, "newname.html"))    

dir_src = "/home/winpc/test/copy/"
navigate_and_rename(dir_src)
```

## Explanation

#### Navigate all files in source folder including subfolders

```
import os
def navigate(src):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            navigate(s)
        else:
            # Do whatever to the file
```

#### Copy to the same folder with new name

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(src_file, dst_file)
```

## Reference

Checkout my [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217797/copy-folder-subfolders-and-files-from-a-path-to-another-path-in-python-via-a-re/44217967#44217967) to another question.

Comment: I found `shutil` is very useful.